# Bootstrap modal in React is not opening

Tags: reactjs

I have a table whose items I render through a list. The idea is that, on clicking the name of a row, a modal will open and that will print certain values retrieved from the backend server. 
Initially, for the modal, my data-target was the ID of my modal. After looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49452472/react-props-state-not-passing-to-modal-window) I realised that I might be doing something wrong and changed that data-target to the ID of the row. Now the problem is that the modal is not opening at all.

Edit: I realised I was doing something wrong when ID of my modal was fixed because irrespective of whichever name I clicked, the same information was loading. Through console.log I could see that the right values were being passed but only was being displayed.

What am I doing wrong here?

The rendered code for the table is as follows:-

```
<table className="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>S. NO.</th>
      <th>NAME</th>
      <th>ADDRESS</th>
      <th>TELEPHONE</th>
      <th>EMAIL</th>
      <th>AGE</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {this.state.personData.map((pRow, idx) => (
    <>
      <PersonModal id={pRow.id} />
      <tr key={pRow.id}>
        <td>{idx + 1}</td>
        <td data-toggle="modal" data-target={pRow.id}>{pRow.name}</td>
        <td>{pRow.address}</td>
        <td>{pRow.phone}</td>
        <td>{pRow.email}</td>
        <td>{pRow.age}</td>
        <td>
          {" "}
          <DeleteButton id={pRow.id} onDelete={this.onDelete} />{" "}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This is the rendered code for the modal:-

```
render() {
  console.log("Component rendered");
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="modal" id={this.props.id}>
        <div className="modal-dialog">
          <div className="modal-content">

            <div className="modal-body">
              {this.props.id}
            </div>

            <div className="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" className="btn optionsButton" data-dismiss="modal">CLOSE</button>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: I usually use the react-bootstrap npm module which works for me but I wonder if adding the # like in the documentation `data-target="#exampleModal"` would help? Or did you try to just manually set the data target to see if it is actually getting triggered?

Comment: @Ren44 no that doesn't work. Seeing as I want to pass a variable value - pRow.id, I'm not sure whether this would be the logically correct approach

Comment: Can you add the id into the class of the modal. That way you know if it is getting injected into the DOM or not?

Comment: @UtsavPatel When I change the ID to a regular fixed ID, the modal opens but then, since I'm passing the ID as a prop to the modal component, it only shows the ID of the first row, irrespective of whichever row I click on

Comment: @sindhugauri Have you tried `<div className="modal" id={\`#${this.props.id}\`}>`

Comment: @SarthakAggarwal yes I tried this too. Set both the 'data-target' and 'id' to this and the modal doesn't open